# ServoBlaster on PI4

Tags: pi-3, servo, pi-4

Could anyone make [ServoBlaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster) work on Raspberry Pi 4? I was able to get it running on PI3 but the same code does not work on PI4.

Comment: Ah, Let me see.  No one can make it work, because the kernel has not caught up with Rpi4.

Comment: Any suggestion how to try to make it work?

Comment: I think either the kernel or daemon are not that well documented for casual user maintenance.  This Servo Blaster thing was designed more than 5 years ago, when PCA9685 was not around. Now everybody is using PCA9685 (check out AdaFruit's PWM and servo breakout board), so no one bothers to spend time doing maintenance.

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01 Do you have recommendation for alternatives of ServoBlaster? My linear actuator is connected to one pin of the PI and I don't want to change the hardware system. I just want to use alternative software package.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I could not think of any alternative without changing the hardware system, of using the Rpi GPIO pins.  There are GPIO extenders such as I2C/SPI MCP230/S-08/17, but it is messy to do PWM with their pins.  I understand the saying "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".  But even if you can hire a geek to upgrade the  drivers, I think it still takes time, and the PCA9685 approach should save you time and money, short term or long term.

Comment: [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) works on the Pi4B.  It is in the Raspbian repository (sudo apt get pigpiod python-pigpio python3 pigpio).  Like servoblaster it will generate servo signals on all the Pi GPIO on the expansion header.  For a quick test use [pigs s](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#S/SERVO).  The PCA9685 is a LED driver and is fairly inflexible as far as driving servos goes.